# Automatically back to command line after roslaunch

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to run roslaunch sequentially with shell script.
I set roslaunch parameter "required = true". It kills roslaunch, but it just shows message "Done!" and does not go back to commandline. So next command cannot be sent.

How can I do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270453/automatically-back-to-command-line-after-roslaunch/) by [mix345](https://answers.ros.org/users/31819/mix345/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-09-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-07**:
Why are you using a shell script to launch different launch files instead of `include`ing the launch files in another launch file?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-08**:
@mix345: could you please tell us what you *actually* are trying to accomplish? @jayess comment makes sense: `roslaunch` can already start multiple launchfiles by itself, so using a shellscript as you (seem to) describe should not be necessary.

**Comment by [mix345](https://answers.ros.org/users/31819/mix345/) on 2017-09-08**:
Hi,
What I want to do is run one roslaunch file for multiple times, with different argument.

It is like
roslaunch a.launch _arg:=1
roslaunch a.launch _arg:=2
roslaunch a.launch _arg:=3
......

So I want to kill the roslaunch after a node finishes and execute next command automatically.

**Comment by [Dickson](https://answers.ros.org/users/43223/dickson/) on 2020-02-25**:
hello @mix345, have you managed to solve this? Am currently running into the same issue.
Or did u go about another method rather then using a python shell script??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Roslaunch will return to command Line as soon as all lauched processes are done. This means all nodes have to stop die roslaunch to Terminate itself, Not just one of the launched nodes. Further, the first roslaunch may open a roscore, which will never terminate by itself so make sure roscore ist already running before starting roslaunch...

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2017-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0